# pygtk - dynamically update the widgets taking input from the gtk combo box

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

On selecting value from 1 to 10 from gtk combox box it should populate the checkbox by taking combo box value as an input. Say for example if i select 5 then 5 checkbox will be generated.
It works.. But the issue is after i selected 5 now im selecting next value as 3 from combo box then there 8 checkboxes are displayed. The old 5 checkbox didnt get replaced. Is there any way to refresh the vbox(which has the checkboxes) or update to a new value.

Enviroment : FC10 , Glade 2 , Python 2.5 , GTK.

Comment: Don't have time to test it right now, but normally you should be able to destroy() the old textboxes before inserting the new ones. See: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code right before you add your comboboxes:

```
for widget in myVBox.get_children():
    myVBox.remove(widget)
```

Comment: Thanks Pynt.. It works... :) I have added right before adding my dynamic checkboxes ...